# I'm trying to connect to a qt application using webdriver-io

Tags: qt, webdriver-io, qtwebkit

I'm trying to connect to a qt application using webdriver-io and It is not able to access the port and does not communicate with the qt part of the application. I could get it to work with Java using the below setup.

```
// Setup QtWebDriver         
DesiredCapabilities capabilityQt = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();     
capabilityQt.setCapability("browserStartWindow", "*");          
// Run QtWebDriver        
WebDriver driverQt = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:9517"), capabilityQt);
```

Can someone provide me a javascript equivalent 
I tried this using selenium-webdriver js but I couldn't get it to work.

```
qtDriver: {             
desiredCapabilities: {                 
browserName: 'chrome',                 
browserStartWindow: '*'},             
port: 9517,             
host: 'localhost'}
```

but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');

var options = {
    desiredCapabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',                 
    browserStartWindow: '*',             
    port: 9517,             
    host: 'localhost'
    }
};

webdriverio.remote(options).init().end();
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above option as well. The only way I could make it work was with selenium-webdriver js driver.

```
var chromeCaps = webdriver.Capabilities.chrome();
chromeCaps.set('browserStartWindow','*');

const qtDriver = new webdriver.Builder()
      .usingServer('http://localhost:9517')
      .withCapabilities(chromeCaps)
      .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');

var options = {
    desiredCapabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',                 
    browserStartWindow: '*',             
    port: 9517,             
    host: 'localhost',
    path: '/'
    }
};
```

You need to specify the path or else it will pick up the default value `/wd/hub`. In this case which is not necessary.